# Can Google Apps account be recovered after org went under, but account is still alive?

Tags: google-workspace

My problems is 2 Factor Authentication.

I was part of a loose online organization which disbanded 2+ years ago, but our mail/docs are still available. I thought I'd log in and check what we were doing (for old times sake).

After entering my email and password, it prompts me to enter a code it sends via sms, but my number has changed well over a year ago (moved countries).

It's been so long ago, I don't think I can make contact with anyone with some sort of administrative privileges. When I click login by other means, it takes me to a page where I can select "request help from Google", but it only takes me to a generic page telling me to contact the administrators.

It's not super crucial, but is there a way I could somehow regain access to my account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for a Google Apps (Enterprise) account it is expected your Admin would allow you back in as they own the account and are paying for the licence cost.

If it were a consumer Gmail account you would be presented with an option to supply additional info that Google would review and decide if you are the actual owner of that account.